# Mark some text in Eclipse editor then type, sometime it replace but sometimes it insert! Why?

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse 2020-06 and there is a wired thing I never encountered in previous versions.

When I mark some text: [image]

Then type (e.g. "M" here) to replace marked text ("m" here), sometime I success as normal but sometimes it become insert and result like:  [image]

My editing mode is always "Insert" and I don't know why. Anybody encounter this or know the secret?

Comment: In which editor? In the Java editor? Which Eclipse IDE packet do you have and do you have additional plugins installed? Is this on Windows, Linux or macOS?

Comment: Yes, Java editor. eclipse-jee-2020-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip is the version I use. Win10 and no additional plugin is installed!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the same Eclipse on Windows 10. Can you reproduce it in a fresh workspace?

Comment: I can't reproduce in a fresh Eclipse installation, either. Maybe I will use it to replace my old installation and see.